# How to display the numbers of integers that the user input?

Tags: java, loops

Sample output is this [image]

```
int nValue, x;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
    nValue = input.nextInt();

    for (x = 1; x == nValue; x++){
        System.out.println("Enter number" + x + ": ");
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am not completely sure of what you are asking, but in your for loop, it should be like 
 this   ->
                                  
for(int i=1;i<=nValue;i++){}

Comment: I think you should add text in a code block instead of the image. Also add the expected output of your program, and what it's currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers exactly what you are trying to ask, but it should give the sample output:

```
// also we dont need the x variable up here
int nValue;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
    nValue = input.nextInt();

    //we increment x, until we reach the `nValue`
    for (int x = 1; x <= nValue; x++){
        System.out.println("Enter number" + x + ": ");
```

Comment: Ty very much! This was exactly what I needed. I didn't notice that I should `x <= nValue` to display it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter value of n: ");
        int n =input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter " + n + " integers: \n");
        
        System.out.print("Enter number 1:");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number 2:");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number 3:");
        int num3 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number 4:");
        int num4 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number 5:");
        int num5 = input.nextInt();
```